# Is there a way to replace all numbers 1 to 100 that are divisible by 3 with a word?

Tags: powershell, sublimetext2

I know that I can go about it this way while writing a long script to test and run however can it be shortened without using so many puts in Sublime since I am using Powershell to run the code?
    puts (1...5).to_a 
    puts "pizza" 
    puts (6..100).to_a

Comment: What's up with the [tag:ruby] code sample? Are you trying to do this in PowerShell or Ruby?

Comment: I'm doing this in sublime then turning it into a ruby file to run in powershell

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
1..100 | %{if ($_ % 3 -eq 0) {'Word'} else {$_} }
```

Comment: We do not need an else block even. Only replaced would do.

Comment: Tested, this does not work without the `else` block.

Comment: @sodawillow: Its working `1..100 | %{if ($_ % 3 -eq 0) {'Word'}}` . Logically you need to replace thats it. So if condition should do that.why we need an else here

Comment: This is only outputting `Word` but I understand that you consider this as the answer to OP's question.

Comment: 1..100 | %{if ($_ % 3 -eq 0) {'Word'}}

Comment: 1..100 | %{if ($_ % 3 -eq 0) {'Word'} else {$_} }

Comment: 1:in `|': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will *replace all numbers 1 to 100 that are divisible by 3* with the word `pizza`. This is a variant of @Esperento57's answer, using a *kinda ternary `if` construction*:

```
1..100 | ForEach-Object { @{ $true = "pizza"; $false = $_ }[$_ % 3 -eq 0] }
```

For each number from 1 to 100, if `number modulo 3 equals 0`, `pizza` is printed out instead of the number.

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @sodawillow much better! +1